# Insert Into Partially Full Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How can we insert integers into a partially full array using java?
The method should take those exact parameters: the array, the count of how many items already in the array, the index of the newly inserted elements and the inserted elements. This is what I have so far.

```
  public static void insertIntoPartiallyFullArray(
      int[] array,
      int count,
      int i,
      int newThing
  ) {
    if (count < array.length || i <= array.length - 1) {
      array[i] = newThing;
      count++;

    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post an example of what you'd like to do? i.e. `a = [9,8,7, 0, 0, 0]; and after calling this method (with newThing = 2) it should be: a = [9,8,7, 2, 0, 0]`

Comment: Yes exactly, it should look something like that

Comment: I still do not understand, what i means.

Comment: i is the index in which the new element should be

Comment: well, why do the function should take the count then? What is the intention of the function?

Comment: To insert elements into the free spots of the partially full array

Comment: To insert elements in the free spots of the partially full array

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static int insertIntoPartiallyFullArray(
  int[] array,
  int count,
  int item
) {
  if (count >= array.length)
  { return array.length; } // the function breaks then

  array[count] = insert;
  return count++;
}
```

the `int`, which is returned is the new count of the array.

the fuction does:

insert an `int item` as the next item in an `int[] array`, which already has `int count` items in it

Comment: the method should not return anything, it should be a public static void, and it has to take those four parameters.